# How to deploy a spring boot application to tomcat server from jenkins?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jenkins, devops

Sample Spring boot application is created and build on Jenkins.

For Deployment of war file in tomcat server ,

I am facing a several issues.

**Error :**

[image: The Error thrown in Build]

**Credentials At Jenkins :**

[image: Tomcat Credentials at Jenkins]

**tomcat-users.xml File :**

[image: Tomcat user xml file.]

Still I am facing the same issue. I had searched in google and stackoverflow but still i can't found the correct answer.

Can Any one help me in this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is a *connection refused: connect* exception. You should check the following:

1. Your Tomcat server is up and running on port 8082 at the same server where your jenkins server is running (localhost). To make sure, run: `telnet localhost 8082` from the same server commandLine ( I see you are in windows). If it connects then your Tomcat server is OK.
2. Check if the manager application of Tomcat is deployed. Try to load the following web page and check if exists: `http://localhost(or hostname of server):8082/manager/html`
3. Try to disable the windows firewall and any other firewall you may have (or antivirus firewall) and check if it prevents jenkins to connect to Tomcat (again check with telnet command)

Comment: Whenever i start my tomcat server using "startup.bat" file, Server is up . The Build in Jenkins gets succeeded without an error but i can't able to access the api. The Server of spring is not up. Whenever i close the tomcat, the connection refused problem arises.

Comment: The result is displayed in http://localhost:8082/SampleProject/index.jsp. I dont know why its displayed here.

Comment: The error on your Question comes from Jenkins war deployment plugin. The error means that Jenkins cannot connect to Tomcat's manager application and Jenkins cannot deploy the Springboot war. If you have resolved that issue and your war is now deployed, you can post a new question with the SpringBoot problem. If you close (stop) tomcat, it is expected to have connection refused exceptions. You have connection refused issues when: a. Nothing is listening on the host:port you are trying to connect to or b. The port is blocked by a firewall.